# Advertencia "DeprecationWarning" al iniciar el servidor de adonis.js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, adonisjs

Estoy haciendo una conexion a mongodb por medio de la libreria de mongoose, y al iniciar el servidor y consumir una ruta me aparece esto:

*(node:3500) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:3500) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.*

Asi que coloque esta opcion **useNewUrlParser: true** donde mongoose hace la conexion, pero no funciono.

MongoseeProvider.js

```
_registerMongoose () {
    this.app.singleton('Adonis/Addons/Mongoose', function (app) {
      const Config = app.use('Adonis/Src/Config')
      let connectionString = Config.get('database.mongodb.connectionString', null)
      const {
        host = 'localhost',
        port = 27017,
        database = 'test',
        user = null,
        pass = null,
        options = {useNewUrlParser: true}, //Solo modifique esta linea para agregar el useNewUrlParser
        debug = false
      } = Config.get('database.mongodb.connection')

      const auth = user ? `${user}:${pass}@` : ''

      if (!connectionString) {
        connectionString = `mongodb://${auth}${host}:${port}/${database}`
      }

      Mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
      Mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
      Mongoose.connect(connectionString, options)

      if (debug) {
        Mongoose.set('debug', true)
      }

      return Mongoose
    })
    this.app.alias('Adonis/Addons/Mongoose', 'Mongoose')
  }
```

Este es mi AuthController, donde intento crear un documento en mi colección:

```
async register ({ request, response }) {

    const data = await MongoUser.find({})
    const IDlatest = data.length + 1
    const id = IDlatest.toString()

    const rules = {
      nombre: 'required|string',
      apellido: 'required|string',
      password: 'required|string',
      correo: 'required|string',
    }

    const validation = await validate(request.all(), rules)

    if(validation.fails()){
      return validation.messages()
    } else {
      var crypto = require("crypto");
      var pin = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');

      try{
        const { nombre ,apellido, password, correo } = request.only([
          'nombre',
          'apellido',
          'password',
          'correo'
        ])

        await MongoUser.create({
          id: id,
          nombre: nombre,
          apellido: apellido,
          password: password,
          correo: correo,
          pin: pin
        })
        
        return response.status(201).json({
          message: "User creado correctamente",
        })
        
        
      } catch (e) {
        return response.status(400).send({'Error': e})
      }
    }
  }
```

Modelo User, aqui asigno los campos de mi documento:

```
'use strict'


/** @type {import('@adonisjs/framework/src/Hash')} */
const Hash = use('Hash')

const BaseModel = use('MongooseModel')

const mongoose = use('Mongoose')

const {Schema} = mongoose

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: Number,
    nombre: String,
    apellido: String,
    password: String,
    correo: String,
    pin: String,
  }
)


class User extends BaseModel {
  static boot () {
    super.boot()

    /**
     * A hook to hash the user password before saving
     * it to the database.
     */
    this.addHook('beforeSave', async (userInstance) => {
      if (userInstance.dirty.password) {
        userInstance.password = await Hash.make(userInstance.password)
      }
    })
  }

  /**
   * A relationship on tokens is required for auth to
   * work. Since features like `refreshTokens` or
   * `rememberToken` will be saved inside the
   * tokens table.
   *
   * @method tokens
   *
   * @return {Object}
   */
  tokens () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/Token')
  }
}
UserSchema.loadClass(User)

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema)
```

Esta es la configuracion de conexion a mongodb:

```
mongodb: {
    connectionString: Env.get('MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING', 'localhost'),
    connection: {
      host: Env.get('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
      port: Env.get('MONGO_PORT', 27017),
      user: Env.get('MONGO_USER', ''),
      pass: Env.get('MONGO_PASSWORD', ''),
      database: Env.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
      options: {
        // All options can be found at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
      },
      debug: false
    }
  },
```

.env

```
MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://localhost:27017/adonismongo
MONGO_CONNECTION=mongodb
MONGO_PORT=27017
MONGO_USER=
MONGO_PASSWORD=
MONGO_DATABASE=adonis
```

Graciass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es que estás sobreescribiendo el valor de `options` con un objeto vacío. Actualmente tienes lo siguiente:

```js
const {
  host = 'localhost',
  port = 27017,
  database = 'test',
  user = null,
  pass = null,
  options = {useNewUrlParser: true}, //Solo modifique esta linea para agregar el useNewUrlParser
  debug = false
} = Config.get('database.mongodb.connection');
```

Sin embargo, tu objeto `mongodb.connection` contiene lo siguiente:

```js
connection: {
  host: Env.get('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
  port: Env.get('MONGO_PORT', 27017),
  user: Env.get('MONGO_USER', ''),
  pass: Env.get('MONGO_PASSWORD', ''),
  database: Env.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
  options: {
    // All options can be found at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html
  },
  debug: false
}
```

Como se observa el valor de `options` es un objeto vacío que sobreescribe el valor que deseas darle en tu `singleton`.

```js
const database = {
  get: function(path){
    let subpaths = path.split('.');
    let data = subpaths.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if(this[acc]) return this[acc][curr];
      return acc[curr];
    })
    return data;
  },
  mongodb: {
    connection: {
      options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
      },
      debug: false
    }
  }
}

const {
  options = { useNewUrlParser: true},
  debug = true
} = database.get('mongodb.connection');

console.log(options);
console.log(debug);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

En el código anterior te muestro que las opciones que tengas en tu objeto `options` dentro de `mongodb.connection` sobreescriben lo que pongas en la asignación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La modificación la debes hacer en tu objeto llamado `mongodb` en el objeto `connection` sobre el campo `options` y no en donde la tienes actualmente.

Por lo tanto lo que debes hacer es escribir el valor en el objeto `options` de `mongodb.connection`:

```js
connection: {
  host: Env.get('MONGO_HOST', 'localhost'),
  port: Env.get('MONGO_PORT', 27017),
  user: Env.get('MONGO_USER', ''),
  pass: Env.get('MONGO_PASSWORD', ''),
  database: Env.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'adonis'),
  options: {
    useNewUrlParser: true // <- aqui debes escribir las opciones.
  },
  debug: false
}
```

De esta forma, cuando ejecutes el código, el objeto de `options` en tu `singleton` contendrá los valores correctos:

```js
const database = {
  get: function(path){
    let subpaths = path.split('.');
    let data = subpaths.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if(this[acc]) return this[acc][curr];
      return acc[curr];
    })
    return data;
  },
  mongodb: {
    connection: {
      options: {
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true // <- aquí se añaden
      },
      debug: false
    }
  }
}

const {
  options = { useNewUrlParser: false}, // <- esto será sobreescrito
  debug = true // <- esto también
} = database.get('mongodb.connection');

console.log(options);
console.log(debug);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.